# Effects of POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED when calculating SHA256 sum with python (TL;DR don't use it)

Tags: python, linux, performance

Update: This is now more for documentation after doing more tests.

TL;DR using POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED isn't worth it. Not using it gives best speed. On AMD64 it even seems not to be respected.

Environment Rasperry PI4 USB 3.0 5TB spinning disk with ext4 file system

Using 1 thread with this config gives the best speed, probably because of the spinning disk.

When calculating the SHA256 sum of all files in a directory tree (checking multiple restic repositories without having to enter the encryption password for every repository), the read spead of the disk is displayed in nmon and with node_exporter almost twice the speed when using `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED`. This argument tells the kernel not to keep the data in the cache. This makes sense because these files are read only once and would otherwise pollute the cache of the system and thus slow it down because other data would miss in the cache.

Without `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` read speed is between 60 and 90 MB/s. With `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` read speed is between 155 MB/s and 175 MB/s, so about twice the speed. This value is shown in nmon and with prometheus node_exporter in combination with VictoriaMetrics. However using the time command gives completly different results. Between each run there was a `' sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

With `posix_fadvise(fd, 0, bytesRead)` time was 37s and slow disk speed was displayed. When using `posix_fadvise(fd, 0, 0)` about twice the disk speed was displayed, but in fact time was 1m8 seconds.
When using

```
def posix_fadvise(fd, offset, length):
    return
```

only 29s where needed, so the fastest results were reached not using `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` at all.

So there is a wrong disk speed shown on Raspberry-Pi, where as more accurate speed is shown on AMD64. On Raspberry PI you can see in VictoriaMectrics and the cache size that it isn't growing when using `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED`, so the flag is respected.

EDIT: On a hosted VM with SSD and much more performance even when using 4 threads, using `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` makes it reproducible about factor 5 slower. Between every run I did `# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
Very strange.

EDIT2: On a physical host using a spinning disk connected via USB3.0 and 1 thread when using POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED it takes 1m25s to read all the files. After clearing cache with `# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and not using POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED it only takes 12seconds to calculate the checksum. So a factor 7 (!) difference.

Update 20.09.2023: With VictoriaMectrics I can see that `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` seems not to be respected regarding cache on AMD64 (on RPi it is, see above), you can see it growing, despite setting the flag.
There is no noticeable difference in speed (using `time`command) between using `posix_fadvise(fd, 0, bytesRead)` (real    1m53,630s user 0m48,819s sys     0m5,627s) and immediately returning in `def posix_fadvise(fd, offset, length):` (real    1m52,675s user 0m51,346s sys 0m6,928s). Using `posix_fadvise(fd, 0, 0)` takes real 2m31,398s user 1m2,004s sys 0m16,178s

```py
import os
import subprocess
import hashlib
import concurrent.futures
import sys
import ctypes

# Constants for posix_fadvise
POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED = 4

base_directory = '/home/pi/5TB'
num_threads = 1  # Adjust the number of threads as needed
# Define posix_fadvise function
def posix_fadvise(fd, offset, length):
    #return #uncomment and speed will be much slower
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
    ret = libc.posix_fadvise(fd, offset, length, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)
    if ret != 0:
        raise OSError(f"posix_fadvise failed with error code {ret}")

def calculate_sha256(file_path):
    try:
        # Calculate the SHA256 checksum of the file
        sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
        bytesRead = 0  # Initialize the counter for bytes read
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            fd = f.fileno()  # Get file descriptor
            # Advise the kernel that we don't need the file data anymore
            #posix_fadvise(fd, 0, 0)            
            while True:
                data = f.read(65536)  # Read in 64KB chunks
                if not data:
                    break
                bytesRead += len(data)
                sha256_hash.update(data)
                posix_fadvise(fd, 0, bytesRead)     
        
        checksum = sha256_hash.hexdigest()

        # Check if the checksum matches the filename
        filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
        if checksum != filename:
            sys.stderr.write(f"Error: Checksum mismatch for file '{file_path}'\n")
        
        return file_path
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stderr.write(f"Error processing file '{file_path}': {str(e)}\n")
        return None

def process_files_in_directory(directory):
    files = [os.path.join(directory, filename) for filename in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, filename))]

    results = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
        for file in executor.map(calculate_sha256, files):
            if file is not None:
                results.append(file)

    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    checked_count = 0
    for root, _, _ in os.walk(base_directory):
        checked_files = process_files_in_directory(root)
        checked_count += len(checked_files)
        if checked_count % 100 == 0:
            sys.stdout.write(f"Checked {checked_count} files...\n")
            sys.stdout.flush()  # Flush the stdout buffer to write immediately                                                                

    sys.stdout.write(f"Checked {checked_count} files in total.\n")
```

Comment: I think you are doing it backwards. Instead of preventing the data from going into page cash, you can simply mmap the file and work within the page cache directly then MADV_FREE on it when you are done. This way you are still using a single copy of the data, but the page cache's copy rather than your local copy.

Comment: By calling `posix_fadvise` with `offset == 0` and `length == 0` you're telling the kernel that you don't need any byte of the _entire_ file, yet you immediately proceed to read from it again. If the kernel has been reading ahead because the bytes are spinning past the read head anyway, that could explain the performance hit. Probably you want to set `length` to the number of bytes you've already read.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used this to do some additional measurements. I've updated the whole post. When not using POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED best speeds are reached on AMD64 as well RasbperryPi.